# Definition Of Saturation current

Tags: semiconductor-physics

In [wikipedia] article about Saturation current(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_current), they define this as

> The saturation current (or scale current), more accurately the reverse saturation current, is the part of the reverse current in a semiconductor diode caused by diffusion of minority carriers from the neutral regions to the depletion region. This current is almost independent of the reverse voltage.

However, as far as I know, the reverse current in a semiconductor is caused by 'drift of minority carriers' and not 'diffusion' (less effect).
Is there an error in this Wikipedia article or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The carriers in a neutral region diffuse to the depletion region. Once there they can drift across.

Comment: Jon Custer gave in his comment the short correct answer!